# Regex OR statement without matching

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex to match one of these two possibilities:

```
(\b(Q|L[A-Z])\d{8}\b)

# Possibilities
LK10652174
Q10652174
```

Now the result for this is:

```
>>> regex.findall(string)
[(u'LK10652175', u'LK')]
```

I don't want it to select the extra `LK` match, Is there a way to encapsule an `OR` statements without getting this extra selection?

Comment: here is a good nice place to test: http://www.pythonregex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a non-capturing parenthesis (and drop the outermost parentheses, you don't need them):

```
\b(?:Q|L[A-Z])\d{8}\b
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, `(?:...)` will match but not capture.

```
(\b(?:Q|L[A-Z])\d{8}\b)
```

Answer (score -1):

From the python docs:

> When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted. This
>   means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it
>   would produce a longer overall match. In other words, the '|' operator
>   is never greedy.

This means you need to write it like this to ensure that the match is the whole string you intend:

```
import re
a = re.compile("(Q\\d{8}|L[A-Z]\\d{8})")
print a.findall("LK10652174 Q10652174")
['LK10652174', 'Q10652174']
```

Comment: that's not true, test it with any of the up voted answers and it will return the same result as yours. what the doc means is that if the first option is matched (Aka, `Q\d{8}`) it will not try the `L[A-Z]` option in that __same pattern__, not in the whole text.

Comment: Fair enough... the capturing group vs. non-capturing group match properties are essential to the explanation of why the original regex did not have the property (A|B)C = AC|AB.